# need help using 2 mfc projects in one solution

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

ive created the first project as mfc application and i have tried to enter the solution another project which created as mfc dll. when i running program the gui from the first solution(demodlg) is shows up. and i want that in a prss of a button in the gui the second gui(CAnalyzerDialog) will show up. i've tried a lot of options and i cant get it done right.
the last option ive tried is this code :
CAnalyzerDialog dlg;
 dlg.Create(CAnalyzerDialog::IDD);
please help. thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set CAnalyzerDialog as primary project?

On solution explorer, right click on the CAnalyzerDialog, tick "Set as startup project".

Probably you are trying to elaborate that:
demodlg - EXE
CAnalyzerDialog - DLL

Check the way you link both project(static or dynamic-runtime/compile time).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the program and DLL both have their own resource files, but MFC is only accessing the program resources and ignoring the DLL ones. Look into AFX_MANAGE_STATE and see if that helps.

Comment: does AFX_MANAGE_STATE  sould be in my solution?

Comment: @adir, not in the solution but as part of the code in the DLL. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9d5yh5(v=vs.80).aspx